# How to change the voice in espeak from python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-to-speech

I'm finishing off a voice assistant project, but I don't like to default voice on espeak.
How can I change it?

From the CLI I can get a nice American female voice:

```
$ espeak -v mb-us1 "hello world"
```

This is the code I'm using to make the computer talk, but it is a male voice:

```
from subprocess import call
speech="Hello World!"
call(["espeak",speech])
```

I don't get how to incorporate the parameters into the call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subprocess.call` takes a list of command line arguments. You just need to pass all of them:

```
call(['espeak', '-v', 'mb-us1', speech])
```

Comment: Perfect... although I feel like I should have been able to work that out now seeing the answer! Many thanks!!!